# Javascript, how to display pop up element after form validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, popup

```js
// Selectors

const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastName = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phonenumber');
const destinationInterest = document.getElementById('destinationinterest');

// Show input error 

function showError(input, message) {
    const formBox = input.parentElement;
    formBox.className = 'form-box error';
    const small = formBox.querySelector('small');
    small.innerText = message;
};


// Show success outline

function showSuccess(input) {
    const formBox = input.parentElement;
    formBox.className = 'form-box success';
};


// Validate email

function validateEmail(input) {
    const  re =  /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (re.test(input.value.trim())) {
        showSuccess(input);
    } else {
        showError(input, 'Email is not valid');
    }
};


// Validate phone number 

function validatePhoneNumber(input) {
    const re = /^\+48\d{9}$/;
    if (re.test(input.value.trim())) {
        showSuccess(input);
    } else {
        showError(input, 'Phone number is not valid');
    }
};


// Check required fields

function checkRequired(inputArr) {
    inputArr.forEach((input) => {
        if (input.value === 'Choose here' || input.value.trim() === '') {
            showError(input, 'This field is required');
        } else {
            showSuccess(input);
        }
    })
};


// Event Listeners

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkRequired([firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber, destinationInterest]);
    validateEmail(email);
    validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

});
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>King Size Travel</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" class="form">
            
            <h2>Subscribe</h2>

            <div class="form-box">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-box">
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-box">
                 <label for="email">Email</label>
                 <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                 <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

             <div class="form-box">
                 <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number <span id="phoneinfo">(Format: +48XXXXXXXXX)</span></label>
                 <input type="tel" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
                 <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-box">
                 <label for="destinationinterest">Destination Interest</label>
                 <select name="destinationinterest" id="destinationinterest" form="form">
                     <option selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
                     <option value="europe">Europe</option>
                     <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                     <option value="northern america">Northern America</option>
                     <option value="southern america">Southern America</option>
                     <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                     <option value="oceania">Oceania</option>
                     <option value="asia">Asia</option>
                </select>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
            
        </form>            
    </div>

    <div class="pop-up">
        <p>Thank you for submitting your interest in our offer!</p>
        <button class="pop-up-button">OK</button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to display pop up which confirms that the form was submitted properly - after clicking the button SUBMIT and after all validations. I do not know how to do it. Maybe do you have any solutions or advices?

I have tried to create a function which will check if all divs (form-box) contains 'success' class and then such pop would display, but it does not work (using forEach)... I am stuck completely.